# Testing input type created by Form Helper

Tags: javascript, cakephp

Is there a way for me to test what kind of input the Form Helper will create before actually creating it. I want to know if the Form Helper will create a select or multi-select, for instance, before the page are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override cakephp FormHelper class to know the which input type will be generate. Then write a custom method which will be return `input type` of field.

```
//cakephp/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php

public function inputType($fieldName, $options = array()) {
    $this->setEntity($fieldName);
    $options = $this->_parseOptions($options);
        return $type = $options['type'];
}

// cakephp/app/view/whatever.ctp
<?php 
      echo $this->Form->inputType('username');
      echo $this->Form->inputType('password');
?>
```

> **output:**
>
> text
>
> password

*I have write method in cakephp Helper Class, you should be override cakephp FormHelper.*